# Instantiating all subclasses in structure map

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm trying to instantiate all subclasses of one class using structuremap.
How would I do this, and how would I control their lifecylce?

I have a base type which other developers inherit to build their classes. At one point I wish to instantiate all of those subclasses and call methods on them.

Comment: Which bit do you want help with, finding which types inherit from your class, or instantiating an object of Type T ?

Comment: Do you want to get a list of all derived types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do batch registration like this:

```
container.Configure(r =>
{
  foreach (var assembly in
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
  {
    r.Scan(s =>
    {
      s.Assembly(assembly);
      s.AddAllTypesOf<MyBaseType>();
    });
  }
});
```

And you can resolve all registered types as follows:

```
IList<MyBaseType> filters = 
    container.GetAllInstances<MyBaseType>();
```